# Detecting method signature in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose we have something like this:

```
    class TodoStore {
      query(state:State):Array<Observable<any>> {
        return state.getAll(); //Custom implementation
      }
    }
```

At runtime I'd like to find all the methods that have a `State` argument as the first argument, so that these can be wrapped by a function that passes in the state argument.  Is this possible with Typescript?

The wrapper class would work approximately like this:

```
class TodoStoreWrapper {
    constructor(private state:State);
    todoStore: TodoStore = new TodoStore();
    query() {
        todoStore.query(state);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking I probably need a @Query() annotation on the query methods as well ... But figured I'd check to see if anyone knew of a reflective way to avoid it ...

Comment: Why not just do that manually? `query() { super.query(state); }` is not that much. Or just add the state property to `TodoStore` ?

Comment: I'd like to have a @Store annotation at the class level that detects all the methods that take a state parameters so that I can wrap that ... which I think is the leanest / most minimal way to have store functionality similar to Ngxs / Ngrx, but without all the boilerplate ...

Comment: Hmmm ... True Dat ... All the implementations of @Store could just have constructor that takes State as an injection argument ... which eliminates the need for the wrapper ... Good thought ...

Comment: "*find all the methods that have a State argument as the first argument, so that these can be wrapped by a function that passes in the state argument*" - this is what decorators are for (which also are explicit instead of relying on brittle typing information), not signature detection at runtime.

Comment: @Bergi true ... but we have to annotate the methods .. just seeing if I can get away with not doing that ... But I agree that it's probably a more robust approach to just use the annotation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While at runtime we don't have the type information to find out which functions have a state parameter, we can at compile time create a type that by its structure requires us to specify in an object literal all methods that have a first argument of type state. While this approach does require us to specify the method it is safe, as the compiler will throw an error if we forget a method and will also throw an error if we specify a name that is not such a method.

We can also combine this with a type that removes the state parameter from all methods that have it :

```
class TodoStore {
    query(state: State): Array<Observable<any>> {
        return state.getAll(); //Custom implementation
    }
    queryWithParam(state: State, p:string): Array<Observable<any>> {
        return state.getAll(); //Custom implementation
    }
}

type StateMethods<T> = Record<{
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends ((s:State, ...a:any[])=> any) ? P : never
}[keyof T], true>

type Wrapped<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]:
    T[P] extends ((s: State, ...a: infer A) => infer R) ?
        (...a: A) => R :
        T[P]
}

function createWrapper<T>(toWrap:T, methods: StateMethods<T>): Wrapped<T>{
    return null as any;
}

let w = createWrapper(new TodoStore(), { // This object will be checked by the compiler to contain the keys of all relevant methods 
    query: true,
    queryWithParam: true 
});

w.query()
w.queryWithParam("")
```

A decorator approach is also possible and you should see which fits better for your use case, but this approach can work as well.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20x%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getAll()%3A%20Observable%3Cany%3E%5B%5D%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Observable%3CT%3E%7B%20v%3A%20T%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20TodoStore%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20query(state%3A%20State)%3A%20Array%3CObservable%3Cany%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20state.getAll()%3B%20%2F%2FCustom%20implementation%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20queryWithParam(state%3A%20State%2C%20p%3Astring)%3A%20Array%3CObservable%3Cany%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20state.getAll()%3B%20%2F%2FCustom%20implementation%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20StateMethods%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Record%3C%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20((s%3AState%2C%20...a%3Aany%5B%5D)%3D%3E%20any)%20%3F%20P%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%2C%20true%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Wrapped%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20((s%3A%20State%2C%20...a%3A%20infer%20A)%20%3D%3E%20infer%20R)%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(...a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20R%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20T%5BP%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createWrapper%3CT%3E(toWrap%3AT%2C%20methods%3A%20StateMethods%3CT%3E)%3A%20Wrapped%3CT%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20w%20%3D%20createWrapper(new%20TodoStore()%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20query%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20queryWithParam%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aw.query()%0D%0Aw.queryWithParam(%22%22))